Solving equation analytically
I was going through an article. I have the following functions,
f[r_] := 1 - (2*M*r^2)/(r^3 + g^3) + (8/3)*Pi*P*r^2
v[r_] := f[r]/r^2

Now I want to solve v'[r]==0 for r. Clearly This cannot be solved analytically. But there they solved it somehow and got the following result.
r = M + M^2/(M^3 - g^3 + Sqrt[g^6 - 2*g^3*M^3])^(1/3) + (M^3 - g^3 + Sqrt[g^6 - 2*g^3*M^3])^(1/3)

Can anyone tell me how can it be solved in mathematica or what method did they use?
Thanks in advance.

in V 14 I get lots of solutions all Root objects. Can you show the complete code you used? But to answer you, basically Mathematica evaluated v'[r] first, then solved the resulting equation  for $r$ . That is all.

You code for r=... is incomplete ?

@MariuszIwaniuk edited

Yours solution for r is only approximation is not equal .You can check it yourself. $r\approx M+\frac{M^2}{\sqrt[3]{M^3-g^3+\sqrt{g^6-2 g^3
M^3}}}+\sqrt[3]{M^3-g^3+\sqrt{g^6-2 g^3 M^3}}$.

f[r_] = 1 - (2*M*r^2)/(r^3 + g^3) + (8/3)*Pi*P*r^2;
v[r_] = f[r]/r^2;

Let's substitute $\rho=r/M$ and $\gamma=g/M$ to simplify the equation:
FullSimplify[v'[r] /. {r -> ρ*M, g -> γ*M}]

$$
-\frac{2 \left(\gamma ^6+2 \gamma ^3 \rho ^3+(\rho -3) \rho ^5\right)}{M^3 \rho ^3
   \left(\gamma ^3+\rho ^3\right)^2}
$$
You are looking for the zeros of this derivative: $\gamma^6+2\gamma^3 \rho^3+(\rho-3) \rho^5=0$, which depends only of $\gamma$:
SolveValues[γ^6 + 2 γ^3 ρ^3 + (-3 + ρ) ρ^5 == 0, ρ]
(*    {Root[γ^6 + 2 γ^3 #1^3 - 3 #1^5 + #1^6 &, 1],
       Root[γ^6 + 2 γ^3 #1^3 - 3 #1^5 + #1^6 &, 2],
       Root[γ^6 + 2 γ^3 #1^3 - 3 #1^5 + #1^6 &, 3],
       Root[γ^6 + 2 γ^3 #1^3 - 3 #1^5 + #1^6 &, 4],
       Root[γ^6 + 2 γ^3 #1^3 - 3 #1^5 + #1^6 &, 5],
       Root[γ^6 + 2 γ^3 #1^3 - 3 #1^5 + #1^6 &, 6]}    *)

Let's make a plot to find out where these zeros are:
DensityPlot[γ^6 + 2 γ^3 ρ^3 + (-3 + ρ) ρ^5, {γ, 0, 10}, {ρ, 0, 10},
            MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> White,
            PlotPoints -> 100]


So only two branches of the solutions are real-valued and usable:
Plot[{Root[γ^6 + 2 γ^3 #1^3 - 3 #1^5 + #1^6 &, 1],
      Root[γ^6 + 2 γ^3 #1^3 - 3 #1^5 + #1^6 &, 2]},
     {γ, 0, 1.4}, PlotLegends -> {1, 2}]


Now you can pick one branch and try to find approximations:
Series[Root[γ^6 + 2 γ^3 #1^3 - 3 #1^5 + #1^6 &, 1], {γ, 0, 3}]
(*    γ^(6/5)/3^(1/5) + 2 γ^(9/5)/(5*3^(4/5)) + 1/25*3^(3/5)*γ^(12/5) + 2*γ^3/45 + O[γ]^(16/5)    *)

So on the blue brach, for small $\gamma$ we have $\rho\approx \gamma^{6/5}/3^{1/5}$, which means $r \approx g^{6/5} \cdot (3M)^{-1/5}$.
For small $\gamma$, the yellow branch is $\rho\approx 3-\frac29\gamma^3$. Your approximate expression also refers to this branch:
$$
\rho \approx 1 + \left(1-\gamma^3+\gamma^{3/2}\sqrt{\gamma^3-2}+1\right)^{\frac13}+\left(1-\gamma
   ^3+\gamma^{3/2}\sqrt{\gamma^3-2}\right)^{-\frac13}
$$
a[γ_] = 1 + (1-γ^3+γ^(3/2)Sqrt[γ^3-2])^(1/3) + (1-γ^3+γ^(3/2)Sqrt[γ^3-2])^(-1/3);
Plot[{Root[γ^6 + 2 γ^3 #1^3 - 3 #1^5 + #1^6 &, 2], a[γ]}, {γ, 0, 1}]


Check the degree of approximation:
γ^6 + 2 γ^3 ρ^3 + (-3 + ρ) ρ^5 /. ρ -> a[γ] // FullSimplify
(*    γ^6    *)

Indeed it looks like this approximation was found by simply neglecting the term $\gamma^6$.
To get a better asymptotic expression for small $\gamma$ we can solve directly,
AsymptoticSolve[γ^6 + 2 γ^3 ρ^3 + (-3 + ρ) ρ^5 == 0, ρ -> 3, {γ, 0, 30}]

(*    {{ρ -> 3 - 2 γ^3/9 - γ^6/27 - 70 γ^9/6561 - 665 γ^12/177147
             - 260 γ^15/177147 - 79112 γ^18/129140163
             - 310726 γ^21/1162261467 - 1260545 γ^24/10460353203
             - 141502900 γ^27/2541865828329 - 599764165 γ^30/22876792454961}}    *)


This was great help. Thanks a lot.

An exact solution, better than the approximation you give, is
r[M_, g_] = M (1/2 + 5/2 HypergeometricPFQ[{-1/3, -1/6, 1/6, 1/3, 1/2},
                                           {-1/5, 1/5, 2/5, 3/5},
                                           (1728 g^3)/(3125 M^3)]);

It satisfies the same limit for small $g$,
Series[r[M,g], {g, 0, 3}]
(*    3 M - (2 g^3)/(9 M^2) + O[g]^4    *)

and it satisfies the equation:
g^6 + 2 g^3 r[M,g]^3 + r[M,g]^5 (-3 M + r[M,g]) // FullSimplify
(*    should give 0 but fails to simplify properly    *)

Plot[r[1, g], {g, 0, (3125/1728)^(1/3)}]



If you want only approximation use: AsymptoticSolve, because exact analytical solution can't be found.
f[r_] := 1 - (2*M*r^2)/(r^3 + g^3) + (8/3)*Pi*P*r^2
v[r_] := f[r]/r^2

NSolve[v'[r] == 0, r, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 20] /. M -> 10^5 /. g -> 10
{{r -> 1.2733095874827712477}, {r -> 299999.9999999777778}}

Simplify[AsymptoticSolve[v'[r] == 0, r, g -> 0, Reals], Assumptions -> M > 0]
{{r -> g^(6/5)/(3^(1/5) M^(1/5))}, {r -> -((2 g^3)/(9 M^2)) + 3 M}}

% /. M -> 10^5 /. g -> 10 // N
{{r -> 1.27226}, {r -> 300000.}}


For me
 res= (  Collect[(D[v[r], r] // 
                  Together // Numerator // FullSimplify), r]

-2 g^6 - 4 g^3 r^3 + 6 M r^5 - 2 r^6

Inserting your (incomplete) root
   res/. 
{r -> M + 
M^2/(M^3 - g^3 + 
      Sqrt[g^6 - 2*g^3*M^3])^(1/3) + 
    (M^3 - g^3 + Sqrt[g^6 - 2*g^3*M^3])^(1/3)} // FullSimplify

   Out[]= -2 g^6

By
 Reduce[0 == -2 g^6 - 4 g^3 r^3 + 6 M r^5 - 2 r^6] /. 
   {a_ == b_ :>   a^3 == b^3} // Union

$$g^3= \pm \sqrt{3 M} \ r^{5/2}-r^3$$
that not really is looking like a solvable equation for $g\ne 0$

I think they made some approximation. I don't think this is an exact solution.

Yes, the approximation sets $g^6\approx0$, which is pretty accurate for small $g$.
